# Rejecting a TCP connection before it's being accepted?

Tags: tcp, winsock

There are 3 different `accept` versions in winsock. Aside from the basic `accept` which is there for standard compliance, there's also `AcceptEx` which seems the most advanced version (due to it's overlapped io capabilities), and `WSAAccept`. The latter supports a condition callback, which as far as I understand, allows the rejection of connection requests before they're accepted (when the `SO_CONDITIONAL_ACCEPT` option is enabled). None of the other versions supports this functionality.

Since I prefer to use `AcceptEx` with overlapped io, I wonder how come this functionality is only available in the simpler version?

I don't know enough about the inner workings of TCP to tell wehter there's actually any difference between rejecting a connection before it has been accepted, and disconnecting a socket right after a connection has been established? And if there is, is there any way to mimic the `WSAAccept` functionality with `AcceptEx`?

Can someone shed some light over this issue?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When a connection is established, the remote end sends a packet with the **SYN** flag set. The server answers with a **SYN,ACK** packet, and after that the remote end sends an **ACK** packet, which may already contain data.

There are two ways to break a TCP connection from forming. The first is resetting the connection - this is the same as the common "connection refused" message seen when connecting to a port nobody is listening to. In this case, the original **SYN** packet is answered with a **RST** packet, which terminates the connection immediately and is stateless. If the **SYN** is resent, **RST** will be generated from every received **SYN** packet.

The second is closing the connection as soon as it has been formed. On the TCP level, there is no way to close the connection both ways immediately - the only thing you can say is that "I am not going to send any more data". This happens so that when the initial **SYN**, **SYN,ACK**, **ACK** exchange has finished, the server sends a **FIN** packet to the remote end. In most cases, telling the other end with **FIN** that "I am not going to send any more data" makes the other end close the connection as well, and send it's own **FIN** packet. A connection terminated this way isn't any different from a normal connection where no data was sent for some reason. This means that the normal state tracking for TCP connections and the lingering close states will persist, just like for normal connections.

Now, on the C API side, this looks a bit different. When calling `listen()` on a port, the OS starts accepting connections on that port. This means that is starts replying **SYN,ACK** packets to connections, regardless if the C code has called `accept()` yet. So, on the TCP side, it makes no difference whether the connection is somehow closed before or after accept. The only additional concern is that a listening socket has a backlog, which means the number of non-accepted connections it can have waiting, before it starts saying **RST** to the remote end.

However, on windows, the `SO_CONDITIONAL_ACCEPT` call allows the application to take control of the backlog queue. This means that the server will not answer **anything** to a **SYN** packet until the application does something with the connection. This means, that rejecting connections at this level can actually send **RST** packets to the network without creating state.

So, if you cannot get the `SO_CONDITIONAL_ACCEPT` functionality enabled somehow on the socket you are using `AcceptEx` on, it will show up differently to the network. However, not many places actually use the immediate **RST** functionality, so I would think the requirement for that must mean a very specialized system indeed. For most common use cases, accepting a socket and then closing it is the normal way to behave.

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment on the Windows side of things but as far as TCP is concerned, *rejecting* a connection is **a bit** different than *disconnecting* from it.

For one, **disconnecting** from a connection means there were more resources already "consumed" (e.g. ports state maintained in Firewalls & end-points, forwarding capacity used in switches/routers etc.) in both the network and the hosts. **Rejecting** a connection is less resource intensive.